# How to localize numerals?

Tags: php, javascript, localization, numbers

Ok, I'm using mathematical equations to output numbers, though, I need this to be compatible for all languages.  Currently, all language strings are within a php array called `$txt`, and each key of the array gets called for that language.  I'm outputting the following:  `Column 1`, `Column 2`, `Column 3`, and so on, as well as `Row 1`, `Row 2`, `Row 3`, and so on.  The calculations are done via php and javascript, so I'm wondering on the best approach for how to support all languages for the numbers only.

I don't do the translations, someone else does, but I need to be able to point it to, either the php variable $txt of where the language is defined, or, since the calculations are done via javascript also, I need to somehow store this in there.  I'm thinking of storing something like this:

```
// This part goes in the php language file.
$txt['0'] = '0';
$txt['1'] = '1';
$txt['2'] = '2';
$txt['2'] = '3';
$txt['4'] = '4';
$txt['5'] = '5';
$txt['6'] = '6';
$txt['7'] = '7';
$txt['8'] = '8';
$txt['9'] = '9';

// This part goes in the php file that needs to call the numbers.
echo '<script>
    var numtxts = new Array();
    numtxts[0] = \'', $txt['0'], '\';
    numtxts[1] = \'', $txt['1'], '\';
    numtxts[2] = \'', $txt['2'], '\';
    numtxts[3] = \'', $txt['3'], '\';
    numtxts[4] = \'', $txt['4'], '\';
    numtxts[5] = \'', $txt['5'], '\';
    numtxts[6] = \'', $txt['6'], '\';
    numtxts[7] = \'', $txt['7'], '\';
    numtxts[8] = \'', $txt['8'], '\';
    numtxts[9] = \'', $txt['9'], '\';
</script>';
```

And than in the javascript function it could grab the correct string for each number like so:

```
// Example Number String below.
var numString = "10";
var transNum = "";

for(x=0;x<numString.length;x++)
{
    var numChar = numString.charAt(x);
    transNum += numtxts[parseInt(numChar)];
}

return transNum;
```

The problem with this bit of code is that it groups the numbers, not sure if all languages do that, like the english language does...?

Perhaps there's a better approach for this?  Can anyone help please?

Thanks :)

Comment: Doy you want the number 123 be presented as "123" or "one hundred twenty three"?

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you want to localize numerals? Like 4 -> 四 in Chinese? Then the approach is much too simplistic. 30000 would properly be 三万 in Kanji, which is a completely different logic. Which languages are you targeting?

Comment: 123, but I need this to be the way it is in other languages also, using numbers.  Unless all languages don't use a numeric system, for instance, if some languages use words, than I suppose I can have it translated into words...  I'm not sure which is better...?  What do you think?

Comment: @ deceze, all languages really.

Comment: I think you should first understand what you're targeting. Arabic numerals work just fine in most cultures, and in many where they don't you'll need to implement different logic. It's not just a matter of swapping characters.

Comment: I wrote garbage. Reading at this early time can be hard...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To properly localize numbers, you'll need much more complex logic. A quick example of roughly what you need to do:

```
function localizeNumber($num, $lang) {
    switch ($lang) {

        case 'eng':
        case ...
            return number_format($num, 0);

        case 'deu':
        case ...
            return number_format($num, 0, ',', '.');

        case 'jpn':
            // TODO: learn about Kanji numerals and implement custom logic
            // Example: 3000 -> 三千, 30000 -> 三万, 321 -> 三百二十一

        ...

    }
}
```

There's not much to do for most western cultures, just some have the thousand separator and the decimal point reversed. If you want to translate numbers into non-Arabic numerals, learn how the target numeric system works, then implement your own logic (or look around for existing libraries).

Also note that although Japanese for example have "their own numerals" (borrowed from the Chinese), these days they usually prefer Arabic numbers. It depends on the context and what image you want to convey though, sometimes Chinese numerals are the better choice. This goes to say that there's a whole lot of culture involved which you need to understand first.

Comment: Ok, thanks, this approach makes the most sense to me.  I'll have to get the translator's to help and hope that `number_format` will be suitable to use for all languages.  Cheers :)

Comment: Bytheway, the target languages are all of the languages listed here: http://dream-portal.net/index.php?action=contribute;sa=translate

Comment: @SoLoGHoST I think you should be fine with Arabic numerals in pretty much all cases there, unless your translators advise you it'd be better to use "local" numerals. In which case, have fun with Hebrew and Chinese... ;)

Comment: hehe, thanks.  Using Arabic numerals will have to do... arggg XD

Answer (score 1):

For Php/Js communication, just use json:

```
echo "var jsArray = " + json_encode($phpArray);
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow json_encode, is this supposed to create an array in javascript with the same key and values as the `$phpArray`?

Thanks, but this doesn't help me with my main problem with languages.

Comment: Thanks nico, will have to look into this.  Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

PHP NumberFormatter is good to use
http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php