# number formatting in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery(function() {
jQuery( "#slider-range-min" ).slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 1,
    step: 1000,
    min: 100000,
    max: 3000000,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        jQuery( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
    }
});
jQuery( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider( "value" ) );
});
```

The field "amount" on our page is filled with the value, but we want this value to be formatted similar to PHPs `number_format` (with commas, etc).

How would I go about doing this in javascript?

Comment: Incidentally, this has nothing to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use two native javascript functions for this.

**[toPrecision()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp)**

```
var num = new Number(65.823474);
var result = num.toPrecision(2); // 65
```

**[toFixed()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp)**

```
var num = new Number(65.823474);
var result = num.toFixed(2); // 65.82
```

However, it does not add the (localized) comma's.

**[Depending on the culture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871195/how-to-localize-numerals)** you are writing for you should replace/insert dots and comma's.

Comment: Alternatives to calling the Number function as a constructor are: `Number(65.823474).toPrecision(2)` and simply `(65.823474).toPrecision(2)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function addCommas(nStr)
{
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

Ref : http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/numberFormat.html

Comment: http://ntt.cc/2008/04/25/6-very-basic-but-very-useful-javascript-number-format-functions-for-web-developers.html can also help you

Answer (score 0):

here i found a pretty good script to format numeric data in javascript, googling a little bit. The code is a little too large, so here's the link to the author's article:

[How to format numbers in JavaScript flexibly and efficiently](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/01/05/javascript-number-formatting/)

The sole thing with it is it uses prototype, so its not "pure" javascript... hope you can use it!

Comment: For scripts to deal with numbers and dates, use: http://www.merlyn.demon.co.uk/#jav